# Upgrade nokia 1100

Tags: lumia

Can Nokia 1100 can be upgradable to Lumia620 .I tried to put lumia620 on nokia 1100 .But no fruitful result I got. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sell it and buy a new Lumia 620 :D

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean please for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the [Nokia 1100 you are referring to is this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_1100), **no it will not support upgrades to any other operating system** let alone some relatively advanced like Windows Phone.